# Reorder ListView items in Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement items reordering with drag and drop on a ListView in Xamarin.Forms but I'm not having any luck.

After googling quite a bit, I found an implementation working for Xamarin.Android (which is my target with Forms for now) and decided to give it a try porting it to Xamarin.Forms.

The basic mechanisms are working (long press to start reordering, animations for swapping items, etc.) but something is still not working. The major problem I have has to do with the items indices not being changed (I suppose).

So, these are the problems I am facing:
- I can't move and item down and then up again without releasing the touch because then the items are moved in a wrong way
- After I moved an item, due to the indices being wrong, I can't touch to select an item because the highlight is showed on the wrong item's line
- after I moved an item it disappears from the list (it is there, but not visible)

I am not that experienced with Xamarin.Forms, and Xamarin in general, so I hope some can give me some hints on what I am doing wrong.

This is the complete code the the custom ListView derived class and its custom renderer: [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/zillemarco/b6623b4e705e4ec46c261013662e1950)

Comment: Easier way, use this: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/listview/gestures/listview-gestures-items-reorder

Comment: Yes I saw that, but we can't afford the Telerik fee for the project

Comment: If you are looking for xamarin android native solution for draggable list then you can check out here : http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2019/08/reorder-list-items-by-drag-and-drop-in.html